# Should I port my Android app to the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, android

I have developed an app for the Android and it's working well, finally, and thanks to all the help from StackOverflow!!

Now I am being asked to make it work on the iPhone. I looked at iPhone a while ago but not recently.

What does everyone think? Should I take the time to learn Objective C and iPhone and port the app or forget it?

Are there any books that cross-reference functions so that you can look up how to do something in iPhone that you already have on Android?

Comment: Unless you wrote a huge chunk in C (Android NDK), then you can forget about re-using stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my experience in school, if you have already been able to create a working smartphone app in at least one mobile OS such as android, it wont take long before you can understand objective C and cocoa framework stuff. The only problem with that is you may probably need an apple developer license to use XCode.

So, I would say go for it since you also get paid, and also here is a link to iphone development guide for android developers : http://integratingstuff.com/2011/02/27/starting-iphone-development-as-an-android-developer/

Answer (score 4):

Probably, it's better to get a partner who develop to iOS than doing it yourself.

Focus on a platform and let your products run to all users.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are using a framework that supports both iOS and Android (something like [the Corona SDK](http://developer.anscamobile.com/user/register?destination=downloads/corona-sdk)) you won't have much actual code that will transfer over.  Ideas, algorithms, logic, graphics, designs, etc will all transfer over just fine.  Those are the hardest parts (IMO) of software dev.

Objective C (the language iOS apps are written in) is not that hard of a language to learn if you already know C-based languages (like Java).  There are a few concepts that are different, but for the most part, it's not that bad.  The biggest challenge for developing on iOS is buying a Mac.  You can program for Android on Windows or Linux boxes, but iOS apps can only be developed on an Apple.  Unless there is something that has happened in the Hacintosh arena that allows for iOS development on other platforms, you're stuck buying new hardware.  **BUT** if you already have a Mac, download XCode and go to town!

Like Haphazard said, if there is enough money in it to make it worth your time, do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting paid, go for it!  (Also, it could be a great learning experience.)

Answer (score 1):

I just learned about this and have not tested it yet, but one thing that you could do depending on the app you have you could take a look at [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/).  It looks pretty promising, though it may not work for your case with your initial application already made.  But in the future this could help.

Answer (score 1):

When I had to make the same decision, I considered the following criteria:

1. how much money is in the app on the other platform ?
2. how many times will this happen in the future, or is this going to be the only app? (how big is the benefit of learning the other platform for the future)
3. how much insider know-how is in the app that one is willing to reveal to another programmer porting this app (in my case I do mostly device handling apps, which is not really all that common)
4. what is the opportunity cost of spending time on porting an app instead of developing another profitable on the initial platform

If you have any possibility, you may look into similar apps and see how they are doing on the two platforms...

Good luck, whatever you are going to do...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you will either have to re-write the app from scratch for iOS, or hand over the job to an experienced iOS developer. You can fairly easily port over the logic and computations in your app from Java to Objective C, but the user interface is the area where you cannot really re-use anything (except maybe icons), and the user interface tends to be a large portion of most apps.

As an Android developer who has ported several of my apps to iOS, I can say that this transition is a hard one. Firstly, you need to buy an iPhone and a Mac (if you don't already have these), since you cannot develop apps for iOS without the Apple hardware. Secondly, you need to learn how to use XCode and Objective C or Swift. And thirdly, since XCode ONLY allows creating the user interface graphically (as opposed to Android which lets you hand-edit the XML), there are many hidden things which can cause you to come unstuck. (UPDATE: Using the new SwiftUI approach to user interface design really helps with this last point, and in my opinion makes the transition from Android to iOS easier).

Finally the Apple and XCode environments seem rather alien to someone who is used to Windows and Android Studio. There are things like the Home and End keys having completely different behaviors to Windows which is frustrating. Also you have to use a combination of key shortcuts and mouse movements to hook up user interface elements to your code. Also, there are big annoyances such as the pop-up keyboard on iOS not pushing the content out of the way automatically like it does with Android. This is probably because Android is an OS designed for multiple screen sizes, whereas iOS is design for a limited number of screen configurations, but it makes iOS feel inferior and harder to work with from a developers point of view. (UPDATE: Using a ScrollView in SwiftUI solves the keyboard obscuring problem).